# How to remove an entry only from one group without affecting other groups in Jabref?

Tags: jabref

I have some entries which belong to multiple groups. But when I try to remove these entries from one of the groups, they are also removed from other groups too. How can I just remove them from one group only without affecting others?

My steps:

1. Choose the group and select the entries
2. Right-click and select `Delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By clicking on Delete, you indeed delete the selected entries *from the file*.

To remove entries from a group (in JabRef 5.0):

1. select the entries
2. in the group panel, right-click on the group and select "Remove selected entries from this group"